# Upload binary data via Java Function App with HttpTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, blob, azure-storage-account

There is a problem with uploading blobs (in fact images), to Blob Storage in Storage Account. I don't want to use `@BlobInput`/`@BlobOutput` annotations because of dynamically chosen container - just don't want to use that.

My function looks like below:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                    name = "req",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.PUT},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
                    route = "image",
                    dataType = "binary")
                    HttpRequestMessage<byte[]> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        String cs = "xyz";

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(cs)
                .containerName("container")
                .buildClient();

        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("blob");
        blobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromBytes(request.getBody()), true);

        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
```

After my function call exception is thrown:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono com.azure.core.util.BinaryData.fromFlux(reactor.core.publisher.Flux, java.lang.Long, boolean)'
      at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlockBlobAsyncClient.uploadWithResponse(BlockBlobAsyncClient.java:425)
      at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlockBlobAsyncClient.lambda$uploadWithResponse$0(BlockBlobAsyncClient.java:410)
```

Maybe current use case can be done in different approach?

Answer (score 0):

It occurs with `azure-storage-blob:12.19.0`. After downgrade to `azure-storage-blob:12.18.0` there is no problem.